# Adding tag count wp_tag_cloud function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display my popular tags and tag count using the `wp_tag_cloud` function.

Here is my HTML code sample:

```
<a href="#">science <span>2</span></a>
<a href="#">tools <span>3</span></a>
<a href="#">music <span>6</span></a>
<a href="#">lahore <span>0</span></a>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got it - here is the solution:

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags('order=desc&number=10');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);  
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} ile ilgili yazılar' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}<span>{$tag->count}</span></a>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CSS like this:

```
a[title]:after{
 content: attr(title);
}
```